# Advice how to create a map out of images

Tags: android, maps

I have to create and offline map using about 20 images (slices of the map),

- I have to put the images together to create the total map,
- I need to be able to zoom in and zoom out
- and to add MARKERS on the map.

What kind of approach could I take to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved creating offline maps by using :

http://www.nutiteq.com/apps/offline-maps-3d/

The tiles for the map you can download from openstreet maps with the tool mobac :

http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks Deacoy, but I must not use openstreet, I have to use the images I have

Comment: You can use whatever images you want.